# How to redirect views block to a display page

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, panel

I want to display a block of my view on the front page. 
This block will have exposed filters.
Once the filters are filled in by the user and he/she submits it
I want the user to be redirected to the results page which the results instead of showing them the results on the same page.

How can I get this done ? Do I need to use panels for this? I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this is quite simple.

You just have to define your page's exposed filters as an exposed form block in your display's advanced options then put this block where you want on your front page.

You can also get more options for the exposed form with the '[Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)' module

Comment: thanks :) I never managed to get this right. I have a follow up question. Once the block redirects the user to the right page then I want the exposed form on the page not to be visible. Is that posssible ?

Comment: Sure, just set the block visibility to `<front>` only :)

In the Blocks admin screen you can click on `configure` right to yours then in the new screen you can see visibility parameters by pages at bottom.

Comment: in drupal 6 this is "Exposed form in block" under "Basic settings"

Answer (score 0):

Easy Vishal - use the block's display properties to do this.

To restrict block to home page only use 'display only on the following pages' and add . To do this the other way around and put it on all pages except your view you would fill in 'display on all pages except' and put in your view url (ie view/listing-of-stuff)